# Can I use IdentityServer4 spa JS UI instead of asp .net core mvc?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I looked example of IdentityServer4 UI ([IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release)) UI in it on the basis of asp .net core mvc. Examples for spa JS UI I have not found. Is is safe to use spa js UI, and how to do it?

Comment: I think it can be done, however I did not find a working prototype for this. I really cannot imagine that this very obvious scenario has not been developed yet. If you are interested about the possible solution, write a comment and I will elaborate my ideas in detail.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: We're interested in a SPA (Angular preferred) UI template for IdentityServer4 as well. Has anybody found/created one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are SPA samples (vanilla JS): https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Clients/src/JsOidc

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I wanted. For example, take the authentication server to make no UI, leave only api methods. A server UI move to a js trusted client.

Comment: 404-Page Not Found. This is a broken link. Please fix it or remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of SPA is to avoid redirects affecting the server. And the idea of Open Id Connect is to redirect every app to authorize endpoint (i.e. sign in page) and back. So the answer should be:

**The Idp has to have at least one server-driven page**

And all the rest are mostly utility pages and might be moved to SPA, separate apps etc. For instance in the suite, I'm currently busy with, we have most UI in SPAs, including user management and so on, but IdSrv is still MVC carrying login/logged-out and a couple error views only.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer is no, IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core per its [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

But you can have SPA UI as client, here is link for SPA samples (vanilla JS) 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Clients/src/JsOidc